Avoid duplicate scheduled task executions across multiple Nginx servers in Spring Boot
I have a Spring Boot application deployed on two Nginx servers. It includes a daily scheduled task to generate reports using the @Scheduled annotation, which triggers the addDailyReports method.
The issue is that the scheduled task runs simultaneously on both servers, causing duplicate reports in the database. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
public void runDailyTask() {
    branchUserService.addDailyReports(null, null);
}

@Override
public String addDailyReports(LocalDate date, Long branchCode) {
    LocalDate reportDate = (date != null) ? date : LocalDate.now();
    
    Long count = branchUserMakerRepos.getCountByReportdateAndReporeFrequency(reportDate, "Daily");
    if (count > 0) {
        return count + " reports exist for the report date " + reportDate;
    }`enter code here`
    
    // Other code to generate reports...
}

I tried database locking to prevent duplicate executions, but it didn't work as expected. Could using @Transactional here solve the issue? If not, what other approaches can prevent this scheduled task from executing twice when deployed across multiple servers?

I recommend using Shedlock dependency, as it ensures that your tasks are executed only once at a time.
To enable Shedlock for the daily task:
@Scheduled(...)
@SchedulerLock(name = "MY_DAILY_TASK")
public void runDailyTask() {
   branchUserService.addDailyReports(null, null);
}

Behind the scenes, Shedlock will add a new row to the shedlock table in the database (see the documentation for configuration details). This ensures that your daily task won’t be executed twice.
And don't forget to enable schedule locking on the application class :
@EnableSchedulerLock(...)
class MyApplication {
    ....
}

